# Problem with PID, temperature won't reach setpoint

Tags: creality-ender-3, creality-ender-5, temperature, pid

Yesterday, I was trying to print with PETG for the first time, I have two printers: an Ender 3 Pro and an Ender 5 Plus.

I started with the Ender 3 where there were no problems with coming up to temperature: nozzle set to 235 °C and the bed at 90 °C. I had to change some settings in the slicer as I forgot support, then I forgot to set a proper Z for the first layer.

So after a couple of times, I run the printer and it's not reaching up to temperature, it stalls around 225 °C; so 10 °C under my setpoint. I try a few times with no success, then I try heating the nozzle by itself with no success, I gave up with the Ender 3.

So I try with the Ender 5 Plus, it happened the same, I try a few times and then it start stalling around 10 °C under the setpoint and then setting off an alarm.
After trying again and again I can see that if I change the setpoint to 245 °C, for example, it will very easily reach 235 °, then I try changing the setpoint a few times and I can see that it stalls around 10 °C under doesn't matter the setpoint.

I tried repowering the machine, I had the cable off the machine all night and this morning it does the same.
My Ender 3 Pro has one only upgrade wich is the touch display.
The Ender 5 Plus doesn't have any upgrades.